# Jquery Mobile Spinner on Blackberry OS5.x

Tags: jquery, blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am a newbie on Phonegap + Blackberry development. I have been working on a Phonegap based web application that runs local html files ant makes Ajax request to communicate with server.

I make a lot of Ajax request in the App, so I need a spinner which tells to user 'app has an interaction with server'. Luckily, I found that Jquery mobile has some useful functionalities for design and performance issues and also spinners.

```
$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
```

Above code works well on Blackbery above OS5 devices but no way on OS5. on OS5 spinner appears but then freezes the UI, it doesn't move and cancel the process.

After some researches, I learn that Blackberry OS5 doesn't have Webkit. Maybe this issue appears due to this reason.

How can I handle this issue, My app must be compatible with OS5 devices, and also I need a spinner. I used CSS based spinners also but they didn't work because Webkit doesn't exist on OS5.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax navigation is disabled in jQuery Mobile for BlackBerry 5 and below.  You will have no spinner because it won't be making ajax requests.  It will be making full page requests so be sure that each page you create can be hit as a stand-alone page.

Comment: Well, is there no way to handle cross-domain communication in OS5?

Comment: There is a potential way.  `script` tags have never had cross domain restrictions.  What you could do is load a script from any domain at all and have that script call return JSON data that you're looking for.  Nothing says that a script src has to be a .js extention, only that it returns valid JS.  So, call a server side URL that will format your data and return it as JSON and then dynamically create the content of your pages.  But, beware. BB OS5 is a POS and processes JavaScript so slowly that you may negatively impact your user experience.

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11844/BB_Browser_content_support_by_version_438586_11.jsp, according to this page, it seems os5 supports AJAX (XMLHttpRequest object) fully. It finally works when I use AJAX - XMLHttpRequest object, For cross-side communication this can be used instead of iframe or script tag etc.

Comment: Huh, cool.  Glad you found a work around.  I was going off of http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/ where they have B-Grade support listed for BB OS5 "B-grade – Enhanced experience except without Ajax navigation features."